# Skype URL "chat with multiple participants" does not work

Tags: html, url, skype

I'm trying to make Skype link on a webpage, which starts a chat with multiple participants.
According to [Skype URL API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745882.aspx), participants in URL should be divided with semicolons. However, following code does not work at all:

```html
   <a href="skype:person1;person2?chat">Start chat (multiple)</a>
```

With only one participant, it works correctly:

```html
<a href="skype:person?chat">Start chart (single)</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do any of the `caveats` listed at your link for multiple chat apply to your situation?

Comment: @PaulT. No. As you, can see, there are no special characters nor topic. And I am using Windows with Opera/Firefox/Edge (none works).

Comment: Well, Windows was not mentioned in the question (nor any other OS), so that's why I asked, especially to the Android caveat.

Comment: I just tried your link and person1 had a profile and avatar, which made me think that those users have to exist for it to work. So I tried it with person1 and another real contact from my contact list, and it worked. So you just have to use a skype username that actually exists.

Comment: @KodosJohnson You're right, that was the problem. Thank you!  PS. Could you make an answer from your comment (you have already posted it, but it was deleted) ?

Comment: @Kao Glad it helped. I undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the link in your first example and noticed that "person1" had a profile picture (a yin and yang symbol), which made me think that those users have to exist for it to work (the "person" in your second example is probably another existing user). So I tried it with person1 and another *real* contact from my contact list, and it worked. So it appears that you have to use a skype username that actually exists.